# Why does Unity3D crash in VirtualBox?

Tags: unity, virtual-machines

I'm running Unity3D in a virtual instance of Windows, using the Virtual Box software on Linux.  I have guest additions installed with DirectX support.  I've tried using Windows XP SP3 32-bit, and Windows 7 64bit.  My host is Ubuntu 12.04 64bit.

I installed and registered Unity on both.  It loads up fine, and then crashes my entire VirtualBox instance (equivalent of a computer shutting off with no warning).

[image: Unity3D pre crash]

Comment: Likely something with the graphics drivers. I'm not sure this is the place for this. Super user maybe?

Comment: I agree with @Byte56.  VMware does some amazing stuff, but instruction passthrough to graphics hardware would be miraculous.

Comment: @SethBattin Apparently VMWare is amazing as you think. However, Virtual Box is not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [Unity forums](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/25394/using-unity-within-virtualbox.html), Unity will not work with Virtual Box.

It does however work with VMWare with the "Accelerate 3D graphics" option checked.

Comment: Ha, good researching. :)

Answer (score 6):

unity3d 4 works on virtual box as well - you need to enable 3d/2d support - 256MB video memory and install the virtualbox Direct3d driver while in windows safe mode

Comment: Which version of Windows did you test on? (VMWare didn't work at all for me, by the way)

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand, I got this working with Windows 7 using VirtualBox 4.3.8. The most important thing was installing the 3D drivers. This guide is for a different purpose but it shows how to install the 3D drivers: http://www.howtogeek.com/124479/how-to-enable-3d-acceleration-and-use-windows-aero-in-virtualbox/

Comment: I gave up. Basically I got a 4.5.5-Pro working on Win-7 but the rendering was most of the time transparent. On my system only the experimental 3D drivers were working.