# small independent game development on a virtual machine

Tags: opengl, c++, sfml, linux

I've been learning about OpenGL and SFML  with c++ now for about 6-8 months, and would like to work on a small little personal game to put some of my skills to the test.

Now I want to kill two birds with one stone, and also increase my knowledge of Ubuntu and linux development in general by developing this project in Ubuntu. Currently my main computer runs Windows 7 while I have an older computer than runs Fedora 18, so I set up an ubuntu 12.04 LTS virtual machine on my main computer. The problem is, what effects does this have graphics wise? I know windows virtual machines running games can often have some graphical and input bugs, should I not use a virtual machine? Or this fine and I'm simply over thinking the subject? Thanks!

Note**

I am using VM VirtualBox on my windows 7 desktop.

Comment: What software is running the virtual machine?  It matters.

Comment: I was thinking of this question when I asked.  It's not a direct answer for you, but it might have some relevant stuff in it.  http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/40625/why-does-unity3d-crash-in-virtualbox

Comment: I do the opposite - I run Arch Linux and develop games in XNA for my classes. Although I have minor issues here and there due to the graphics driver, it works well.

Answer (score 4):

So long as you are fine sticking to the version of GL provided by [VirtualBox Guest Additions](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html) you should be okay.  Performance will be a worse than native but even professional-grade GL apps and games can work quite well inside a VirtualBox VM.  I'm been led to believe that [VMWare Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/) has better GL support for guests but I have not personally compared them.  I would try both, see which one works better for you (of if they work at all).

Short version: just try it and see.